# How to Compare hash values

Tags: perl

I want to compare hash values as below. 
I need to check....

---> if all the hash values are "SUCCESS", then print a message only once.

---> else if even a single value is "FAILURE", then print another message only once.

Please note that I need to print the message in either case **ONLY ONCE**

This is my code ( with the one of the values being "FAILURE")

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $hash = {
                1   =>  'SUCCESS',
                2   =>  'SUCCESS',
                3   =>  'SUCCESS',
                4   =>  'FAILURE',
            };

foreach my $key ( keys %$hash )
{
    if ($hash->{$key} eq 'FAILURE')
    {
        print "One of the Keys encoutered failure. Cannot proceed with Automation \n";
        last;
    }
    elsif ($hash->{$key} eq 'SUCCESS')
    {
        next;
        print "All the Keys were successful. Proceeding to Automation \n";
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
One of the Keys encoutered failure. Cannot proceed with Automation
```

This is working fine when one of the keys contain "FAILURE".

BUT..... This is not working when all the values are "SUCCESS":

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $hash = {
                1   =>  'SUCCESS',
                2   =>  'SUCCESS',
                3   =>  'SUCCESS',
                4   =>  'SUCCESS',
            };

foreach my $key ( keys %$hash )
{
    if ($hash->{$key} eq 'FAILURE')
    {
        print "One of the Keys encoutered failure. Cannot proceed with Automation \n";
        last;
    }
    elsif ($hash->{$key} eq 'SUCCESS')
    {
        next;
        print "All the Keys were successful. Proceeding to Automation \n";
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
huh..there is no output. It brings me back to the bash shell.
```

Now, If I comment the `next` from the `else` loop, then it prints hte statement 4 times.

```
All the Keys were successful. Proceeding to Automation 
All the Keys were successful. Proceeding to Automation 
All the Keys were successful. Proceeding to Automation 
All the Keys were successful. Proceeding to Automation
```

**QUESTION**:

So, In this case I want to print the statement "All the Keys were successful. Proceeding to Automation" **only once.**  How can i do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `next` is causing the loop to immediately skip to the next iteration. That's why you don't see any output -- the program execution never reaches the `print` statement following the `next`.

What you can do is use a flag variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $hash = { 1   =>  'SUCCESS',
             2   =>  'SUCCESS',
             3   =>  'SUCCESS',
             4   =>  'SUCCESS',
           };

my $failure = 0;
foreach my $key (keys %$hash)
{
  if ($hash->{$key} eq 'FAILURE')
  {
    $failure = 1;
    last;
  }
}

if ($failure == 1) {
  print "One of the Keys encoutered failure. Cannot proceed with Automation \n";
} else {
  print "All the Keys were successful. Proceeding to Automation \n";
}
```

Comment: You could additionally shortcut the failure check with adding a `last;` after setting the failure variable since there is no need to check all hash values if one is already faulty.

Comment: @dgw: Good catch, added that in.